# Gsm and Touch display on Raspberry pi

Tags: touchscreen, gsm

Im trying to connect a touch display and a gsm module with rasberry pi at the same time , but the pins which are needed to connect the gsm module with rasberryy pi module are already occupied by the touch display.can anyone help me how to connect them both with pi module , if so , which pins are exactly needed to be connected for the gsm and touch display respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
P2 - Power to Display
P4 - Power to GSM
P6 - Ground to GSM
P8 - Transmission to GSM
P10 - Receiver From GSM
P11- P13-  Connection to Display
P14- Ground to Display
P15 - P16 - Connection to Display
P18 - Connection to display
P19-P26 - Connection to the Display
```

Follow the Pins  as given both the display and gsm modules are working good